# Gimbal platform control using a DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, control-system, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, pid-controller

I need to make a gimbal stabilization platform for a project. I should be able to control both speed and position (a servo or stepper motor are not suitable for this reason.) There are DC motors with brushed or brushless encoders, but I want the response time to be short for stabilization.

Can I provide position stabilization with a DC motor with encoder, or is the right choice a brushless motor?

Comment: I'm projecting perhaps. But how are you on legendre transform, lagrangians, hamiltonians, phase space, etc?

Comment: Presumably any position encoder would be better off on (each axis of) the platform itself, not on the motor though a tacho generator could be helpful on a DC servomotor. I'm afraid AC motors with ESC are more recent than my control theory lectures. You will need a considerable chunk of control theory to optimize your system response.